# bootstrap-datepicker manually entered date issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [this bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and everything works fine except the input field doesn't allow to add a date manually or at least it doesn't work properly for manually entered inputs.

Here are the current options in javascript:

```
$(function(){
        $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
            endDate: "today",
            todayBtn: true,
            forceParse: false,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });        
});
```

1) First issue is when the date is typed and "enter" key is pressed the date is gone.
2) When delete the date and start typing a new date the datepicker acts weird.

Hope someone could figure out how to fix the manually entered date?

Maybe having a calendar icon beside each input and have the datepicker triggered only from there would be a good option and leave the text input only for typing.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg8f75bt/) to play with.

Comment: Having a similar issue with bootstrap-datepicker. The on 'changeDate' event does not fire when the enter key is pressed after a date has been manually updated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After digging around on the GitHub found a couple of fixes that haven't been implemented in the main bootstrap-datepicker.js file yet. Just thought that it would be helpful for someone experiencing the same issues until the new update comes in:

1) [Issue No1](https://github.com/dhruvparmar372/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/master): "Enter" key removed the input when entered manually - FIXED

2) [Issue No2](https://github.com/jonr22/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/2ce4cabce4d0368e87bc6a8be10be82d6463ce9a): In the Date Range option when the second input is being deleted with "Backspace" key the first input is loosing it's last character - FIXED

The above two fixes have to be done in bootstrap-datepicker.js file.

Comment: The first link indeed takes care of the value being lost when manually entering dates.